# Умножить элементы массива

Tags: javascript

```js
const arr1=[2,2,2]
        const arr2=[3,3,5]
        let i, a
        for (i=0; i<arr1.length; i++) {
        for (a=0; a<arr2.length; a++) {
        }
        console.log(arr1[i] - arr2[a]);

    }
```

Как умножить массив на массив?
Умножить каждый элемент массива на каждый элемент второго массива
Массивы поступают одинаковой ширины

Спасибо за каждый ответ

Comment: А что должно в итоге получиться? Вот хотя бы для приведенных в вопросе `arr1` и `arr2`.

Comment: операция "-" вычитание

Comment: Через один цикл и одинаковые индексы `console.log(arr1[i] - arr2[i])`, внутренний цикл с `a` лишний.

Comment: ааа ок поробую....

Comment: "Каждый элемент на каждый элемент...", а с результатами перемножения элемента первого массива на каждый элемент второго что нужно сделать, сложить или тоже умножить? Или перемножение по совпадению индексов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const resultingArray = arr1.map((currentValue, index) => x - arr2[index])
```

ну или

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr1[i] - arr2[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];
const resultArr = [];

if (arr1.length === arr2.length) { // если длина двух массивов одинаковая
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    const computation = arr1[i] * arr2[i];
    resultArr.push(computation);
  }
}

console.log(resultArr);
```